# Gradle Eclipse Classpath Exception: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

[image: **enter image description here**]

I am getting the error as attached in the image above whenever I am trying to run gradle eclipse. 
I keep on getting this eclipseClassPath exception.

The Gradle Version, I am using is 3.1
Someone suggested me to use gradle version 2.14 because it won't work with the latest version of gradle.

> My build.gradle file is below:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
        springCloudConnectorsVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
        jarName =  'comOrderAudit'
        jarVersion = ' -jar build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.0.RELEASE")
    }   
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }

    "org.springframework.cloud:Spring-cloud-core:${springCloudConnectorsVersion}" 
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:${springCloudConnectorsVersion}" 
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:${springCloudConnectorsVersion}" 
    compile 'org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.8'

    compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.8' 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-oxm'
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.wordnik:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.8'    
    compile  'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testCompile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'

}

task updateVersion{
    Properties props = new Properties()
    File propsFile = new File("src/main/resources/application.properties")
    props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
    println(props.getProperty("buildNumber")+"v")
    Integer nextbuildnum = (((props.getProperty("buildNumber")) as Integer) + 1)
    props.setProperty('buildNumber', nextbuildnum.toString())
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
    props.setProperty("buildTimeStamp", formattedDate)
    props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
    props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
}

test {
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
    jacocoTestReport{
        group = "Reporting"
        description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports."
        additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.java)
        reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
        }

        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it,
                        exclude: ['**/model/**'])
            })
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer through extensive search.

Looks like the issue was with Spring boot version used in the gradle.
With Gradle version 3.1, the recommended spring boot version is 1.4.x releases.
If I am to use spring boot version 1.2.3 the gradle version I should be using is 2.14. 
just changed the spring boot version and the build was success.

For more answers you can take a look at this page [here.](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-3-1-fails-with-unsupportedoperationexception-and-works-on-gradle-2-14/20022)